# Cakephp simple drop down list without database values

Tags: php, cakephp, drop-down-menu, cakephp-2.3

How to create a simple drop down list in Cakephp where I want only three values to be shown and the values will not be coming from database. I searched for it but all I got is how to show database values in drop down. But I don't need that. I have a leave application form using which an employee can apply for leave. That application goes to admin and he can select three statuses which are: Approve, Put On Hold, Reject.
I tried this in add.ctp page:

```
$options = array('Approve', 'Put On Hold', 'Reject');
$selected = array('Put On Hold');
echo $this->Form->input('leave_status', array('multiple' => true, 'options' => $options, 'selected' => $selected));
```

but it is not adding the status of leave and page goes blank and the drop down menu is also not like what normally it is. It shows all three options like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple) but I want it like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select)
Any kind of help or hint will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See [static enums](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/) as a DRY approach including bake template support.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $this->Form->input('leave_status', array( 'options' => $options, 'selected' => $selected));
```

'multiple' => true  is not needed

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But Put On Hold is not selected. How to achieve that?

Comment: try `$selected = 0` as 0 is the index of the selected option

Comment: pardon:  $selected = 1 as 'Put on Hold' has index 1

Comment: Thank you XuDing and arilia.

Comment: "selected" is wrong. Either use default or better set defaults via controller as shown [here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/) to properly populate forms (non-persistent after validation/post).

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this code.....
    <?php 
$options = array('Approve'=>'Approve', 'Put On Hold'=>'Put On Hold', 'Reject'=>'Reject');
echo $this->Form->input('leave_status', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $options, 'selected' => 'Put On Hold'));
?>
```